# Joining a string and separating it using multiple separators

Tags: c#, string, join

My curernt method will send a list of trades that look like this: "name;quant;name;quant" etc....

I want to be able to send it like this: "(name;quant), (name;quant)", that way the client has it in a more readable fashion for them.

I didn't see a way to do this on the MSDN site, and the examples here were all in Python.

```
     public void Send(Socket handler, List<String> trades)
        {
            //Converts List into string
            var result = string.Join(";", trades.ToArray());
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            //calls the object to array method to convert it to a byte array
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have a `List<String>` if it should actually be a list of a class or Tuple? (Something with a name and a quantity)

Comment: For clarification: is the array like this: `"name", "quant", "name", "quant"`, or is it `"name;quant", "name;quant"`?

Comment: The array is like the former...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).

Assuming your data is in the list in format: "name;quant" you can use this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("(");
for (int i = 1; i <= trades.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append(trades[i]);
    sb.Append(")");
    if (i < trades.Count)
    {
        sb.Append(", (");
    }
}
```

Otherwise if your list is like "name","quant","name","quant" you can use this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("(");
for (int i = 1; i <= trades.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append(trades[i]);
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        sb.Append(";");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(")");
        if (i < trades.Count)
        {
            sb.Append(", (");
        }
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if each `trade` is already like `name;quant`:

```
string result = trades.Count == 0 ? 
    string.Empty : 
    "(" + string.Join("), (", trades.ToArray()) + ")";
```

Note that in newer versions of .NET you don't need the `.ToArray()` in `trades.ToArray()`:

```
string result = trades.Count == 0 ? 
    string.Empty : 
    "(" + string.Join("), (", trades) + ")";
```